# Secure Laptop 2fa

Tags: windows, security, encryption

How can I secure my notebook with highly sensitive information stored in a spreadsheet.

I am keeping the following options in mind:

- Password protect & encrypt BIOS
- Encrypt entire disk
- Password protect the spreadsheet

Is it possible to do 2fa for windows signon?

Which other options are there?

Answer (score 0):

- Use a full disk encryption. There are some on the market - especially for
  windows.
- Use a full disk encryption, that works well with a 2nd factor - I would request a smartcard/certificate token.
- Lock your BIOS - yes.

Or wipe your Windows and use a non-eavesdropping distribution. You might even look at "tails".